# how to bind a bind_param with non variables

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a funktion that is suposed to make it easy to make prepared sql querys

here is the function

```
    function preparedConnection($stmt,$param){ 
    $dbUsername= 'root';
    $dbPassword='';
    $dbip = 'localhost';
    $db = '129393';

    $conn = new mysqli($dbip, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo $stmt."<br>";
    $stmt_db = $conn->prepare($stmt);
    echo $param;
    $stmt_db->bind_param($param);


    $stmt_db->execute();
    $stmt_db->close();
    $conn->close();
    exit();
}
```

here is how i use it

```
       $stmt = "INSERT INTO task_times (task_id, login_id, title, description,
    used_fixed_price_per_hour ,used_discount_percent, used_price_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $param = "'iissiii', $task_id , $login_id, '$title', '$description', $used_fixed_price_per_hour, $used_discount_percent, $used_price_type";

    $db->preparedConnection($stmt,$param);
```

but i does not accept vaiables that are string eny help?

Comment: what you are trying here with `$param` just doesn't work. You cannot pass multiple arguments wrapped in a single string..

Comment: and there is not a hack for this ?

Comment: either make `$param` an array and use things like [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call bind_param; or use PDO where you can pass in an array as params

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass each parameter to `bind_param()` individually.

A possible solution that gives you a bit more flexibility than hardcoding it, would be to use [array unpacking](https://www.php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list): You pass an array with all individual values and unpack it where you need it:

```
$param = [
    'iissiii',
    $task_id,
    $login_id,
    // etc.
];
```

And in your function:

```
$stmt_db->bind_param(...$param);
```